# Parameters not working with Dapper.Net

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, dapper

I've downloaded the **SqlMapper.cs** file from the link *[here](https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/)*.

Though I'm having a bit of confusing trouble. Whenever I use parameters my queries return empty collections, even though I'm quite sure I'm using the same string data.

Here is a snippet of code that is used to extract the data.

```
using (PhoenixConnection connection = new PhoenixConnection(Open: true))
{
    //this example works, returns 1 token object
    string queryWorks = @"Select AccountName, AccountToken from btsource.accounts
    where AccountName = 'RekindledPhoenix'";

    // replaces 'RekindledPhoenix' with a parameter, returns empty collection
    string queryDoesnt = @"Select AccountName, AccountToken from btsource.accounts 
    where AccountName = @AccountName";

    var tokenList = connection.Query<TokenRequest>(queryWorks);
    var tokenList = connection.Query<TokenRequest>(queryDoesnt, new { AccountName = "RekindledPhoenix" });
    return tokenList.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Here is my class I'm using...

```
public class TokenRequest
{
    public string AccountName { get; set; } //`AccountName` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    public long AccountToken { get; set; } //`AccountToken` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL
}
```

And here is the wrapper function in my PhoenixConnection object.

```
public IEnumerable<T> Query<T>(string Query, dynamic Parameters = null)
{
    return _connection.Query<T>(Query, (object)Parameters);
}
```

I've tried:

- double-checking mysql table names and values
- changing wrapper to use anything but dynamic (didn't work)
- verifying connection *is* open
- raw mysqlConnection object, commandtext, etc

What could I be **missing**?

Is there some special setting used for parameters?

### Edit:

Using raw `MySqlConnection` parameters work better with `?` and not `@`, though still doesn't work with Dapper.

I noticed there were specific lines within Dapper that extract parameters with regex (`[@:]`) statements, though question marks seem to be ignored. What should I change to give me the expected results?

Comment: What is PhoenixConnection? It isn't one I am familiar with. If you were writing this with raw ADO.NET (CreateCommand, Parameters.Add etc) - does that work?

Comment: @MarcGravell Yes, `PhoenixConnection` is a small wrapper to handle connection state, dispose, etc. Parameters work with `MySqlConnection` class but only when _question marks_ are used.

Comment: It really depends on what MySql Connector version you're using. Some (Eg. 5.2.7) does work with '@' while others don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the issue. After using a raw `MySqlConnection` object to execute my queries, it lead me on a search for why `@` symbols didn't work in any of my statements. In the past I've always used `?`, so this behavior was odd to me.

### Changing SqlMapper.cs

Change the following `@` symbols to a `?` *(with approximate line numbers)*:

Line 1863:  `if (identity.sql.IndexOf("`***?***`" + prop.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) < 0`

Line 1831:  `return parameters.Where(p => Regex.IsMatch(sql, "[`***?***`:]" + p.Name + "([^a-zA-Z0-9_]+|$)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline));`

Solved my problem!

Comment: Well, that's just embarrassing for me; will investigate and fix that for the next deploy